# Node.JS module to retrieve configuration from environment variables

Tags: javascript, beginner, node.js, configuration, constants

I don't like the idea of sprinkling process.env all over the place and wanted to abstract it out a bit. I'm new to Node and know there must be a better way to do a few things.

1. Not repeat the name 4 times (twice as a string and twice as a field)
2. Any cleaner way to create properties and centralize existence checks than how I've done it? Mind you, I am trying to keep this Node 4.3.2 compatible sans Babel transpilers to keep it simple and working in AWS Lambda's NodeJs environment.

```
// module

module.exports = {

}

var configError = function (keyName) {
  console.error("ExternalVars error! Could not load a value for: "+keyName);
  process.exit(1);
}

// TODO: extract repeated function?
Object.defineProperty(module.exports, 'SAMPLE_SECRET', {
    get: function() {
        if (!process.env.SAMPLE_SECRET)
            configError('SAMPLE_SECRET');
        else
            return process.env.SAMPLE_SECRET;
    }
});

Object.defineProperty(module.exports, 'SAMPLE_SECRET_MORE', {
    get: function() {
        if (!process.env.SAMPLE_SECRET_MORE)
            configError('SAMPLE_SECRET_MORE');
        else
            return process.env.SAMPLE_SECRET_MORE;
    }
});

// usage example

var externalvars = require('./config/externalvars.js');

var sampleSecret = externalvars.SAMPLE_SECRET;
var sampleSecretMore = externalvars.SAMPLE_SECRET_MORE;
```

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: since I'm not familiar with export/import realm, my suggestion below might be too naive and not work. If so, rather than **only** downvoting, thanks in advance for a little comment pointing me to a resource which would enlight how and why I'm wrong.*

That's said, with merely my pure JS skills, here is how I'd work:

```
var keys = [
  'SAMPLE_SECRET',
  'SAMPLE_SECRET_MORE'
];
keys.forEach(function(keyName) {
  Object.defineProperty(module.exports, keyName, {
      get: function() {
          if (!process.env[keyName]) {
              console.error(
                "ExternalVars error! Could not load a value for: " + keyName
              );
              process.exit(1);
          } else {
              return process.env[keyName];
          }
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: This nicely removes the redundancy but for reasons I don't understand evaluates the getter without me calling it. For instance I set a value of process.env.SAMPLE_SECRET and then ask for it back and it tells me it can't find a value for SAMPLE_SECRET_MORE despite not asking for it.

Comment: @ss2k "evaluates the getter without me calling it": that's inherent to the way my proposed snippet works. And reading your comment I understand it doesn't exactly fits your need. In other words I believed you wanted to have something like a general configuration (hence my `keys` list), which would be early prepared for each registered key. Now you might consider replacing my `keys.forEach(function(keyName) {...});` by `function(keyName) {...}` and invoke it when needed. BTW I realized my code was abruptly terminated, missing `);` at the end. Corrected.

Comment: I wasn't able to replace as you had suggested without a syntax error. Can you write out your alternate version?

Comment: @ss2k My "alternate version" is merely what I wrote in my previous comment. In other words, embed the `Object.defineProperty()` statement in a function, say `processEnv(keyname)`, then call it when needed, e.g. `processEnv(SAMPLE_SECRET)`.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but this should be equivalent to yours:

```
const requiredKeys = ['SAMPLE_SECRET', 'SAMPLE_SECRET_MORE']

const keyValues = requiredKeys.reduce((m,x) => {
  if (!process.env[x]) {
    console.error("ExternalVars error! Could not load a value for: "+keyName)
    process.exit(1)
  }
  m[x] = process.env[x]
  return m
}, {})

export default keyValues
```